# how to implement mutexes in a callback function which is called by multiple threads at the same time

Tags: c++, timer, window, mutex

Am trying to create a timer functionality using Windows timers, which will be called by multiple threads running concurrently. The callback function modifies a global array. I have used mutexes but am not sure if I am doing it correctly. In my CreateTimer and DeleteTimer do I need mutexes also, Or is having it in the callback function enough?
My code is as follows:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <errno.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct
{
    uint32_t  msgId;
    uint32_t  param1;
    uint32_t  param2;
}THRD_EVENT_T;


enum THRD_EVENTID_T
{
    THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST,

    THRD_STATEA,
    THRD_STATEB,
    THRD_STATEC,
    THRD_STATED,
    THRD_STATEF,

    THRD_MSGID_TIMER_LAST
}


HANDLE   hTimerQueue = 0;
HANDLE   tmrHdl[THRD_MSGID_TIMER_LAST - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST] = { 0 };
uint32_t rParam[THRD_MSGID_TIMER_LAST - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST] = { 0 }; 
int32_t  rPipe[THRD_MSGID_TIMER_LAST - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST] = { 0 };

std::mutex m;



VOID CALLBACK TimerCallback( PVOID lpParam, bool TimerOrWaitFired )
{
    m.lock();
    uint32_t tmpPrm = *( uint32_t* )lpParam;
    THRD_EVENT_T tBuff;
    int txd;
    if ( lpParam != NULL )
    {
        tBuff.msgId = tmpPrm;

        // global flags to be set go here
    }

    // delete the timer
    DeleteTimerQueueTimer( NULL, tmrHdl[tmpPrm - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST], NULL );
    // clear the items in array
    tmrHdl[tmpPrm - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST] = 0;
    //    rPipe[tmpPrm - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST] = 0;
    //    rParam[tmpPrm - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST] = 0;
    // do not clear the array data - concurrency issues
    m.unlock();
}


int32_t CreateTimer( const THRD_EVENTID_T timerId, const int32_t pipeId, const uint32_t msPeriod )
{
    // m.lock();
    int32_t ret = -1;
    if ( 0 == hTimerQueue )
    {
        hTimerQueue = CreateTimerQueue();
        if ( 0 == hTimerQueue )
        {
            DbgPrint( "FAULT - failed to create timer queue!\n" );
        }
    }

    if ( 0 == tmrHdl[timerId - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST] )
    {
        if ( false == CreateTimerQueueTimer( &tmrHdl[timerId - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST], hTimerQueue,
            ( WAITORTIMERCALLBACK )TimerCallback, &rParam[timerId - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST], msPeriod, 0, 0) )
        {
            printf( "FAULT (%d) - failed to create timer!\n", GetLastError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //set some flags
            ret = 0;
        }
    } // if
    else
    {
        printf( "FAULT (%d) - failed to create timer!\n", GetLastError() );
        printf( "\nexiting the loop for timer creation: failed to create timer \n" );
        ret = -1;

    }

    //  m.unlock();
    return ( ret );
}

int32_t DeleteTimer( const THRD_EVENTID_T timerId )
{
    // m.lock();
    int32_t ret = -1;
    // delete the timer
    DeleteTimerQueueTimer( hTimerQueue, tmrHdl[timerId - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST], NULL );

    // clear the items in array
    tmrHdl[timerId - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST] = 0;
    rPipe[timerId - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST] = 0;
    rParam[timerId - THRD_MSGID_TIMER_FIRST] = 0;
    // m.unlock();
    return ( ret );
}
```

Comment: When I read your code, I'm wondering why the question is tagged C++ since the only C++ thing I can see is `#include <mutex>`. In the same line, drop the `typedef` before declaring structs/classes in C++. Be really careful when you compile C code with a C++ compiler. They are different languages and the rules for a given instruction may differ from one to the other.

Comment: Can `CreateTimer` be called concurrently by multiple threads? If so, you have a data race on `hTimerQueue`

Comment: `if ( lpParam != NULL )` It's a bit too late to check for that **after** you've already done `*( uint32_t* )lpParam`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes it can be called concurrently, how would I avoid the data race on `htimerQueue` ?

Comment: Well, for example, by protecting access to it with a mutex.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i am using mutexes in callback function, would you say they are appropriate? or should I use them in the createtimer and deletetimer functions as well?

Comment: In `TimerCallback`, `DeleteTimerQueueTimer` passes `NULL` for the timer queue handle. This is only valid if `NULL` was also passed to `CreateTimerQueueTimer` - but it wasn't.

Comment: `CreateTimer` and `DeleteTimer` manipulate shared state, and you say they can be called concurrently. Concurrent access to shared state must be protected, whether with a mutex or some other synchronization mechanism.

Comment: And yes, you also have a race on elements of `tmrHdl` between all three of `TimerCallback`, `CreateTimer` and `DeleteTimer`. And on `rParam`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik would you if possible provide an example of how to avoid the race conditions and protect the shared elements?

Comment: Well, the simplest way would be to have all three functions lock the mutex, as you propose in commented-out lines.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik do you think they would be any deadlock if I use mutexes in all my functions?

Comment: No, I do not so think.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik would you advice for one mutex for all the functions or should each function have there own mutex?

Comment: It must be one mutex. Having a separate mutex per function won't protect anything. Mutexes protect data, not code - for a mutex to actually be useful, all access to a piece of shared data, from anywhere, must be under the same mutex.

Comment: Mixin timers with threads... what could possibly go wrong? Maybe you could better explain what you want to achieve. I have the feeling there is a much more elegant way then mixing threads with the windows API (which is not threadsafe)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, I will have multiple threads, that want to create timers asynchronously (non blocking). As a simple example I have an Rx thread and a Tx thread where the Tx thread will initiate a timer while th Rx thread will delete the timer if the response is recevied. if the timer timouts a callback function is called.  I have approximately like 5-6 threads which will  be creating and deleting timers.

Comment: That's still describing how you want to do it.  Seems you like to want to receive data and want to timeout if you don't get it in time. If so their are better (non-os specific) approaches. Like using condition variables, lambda functions and std::async/std::thread

Comment: On a side note: do not call a mutex's `lock`/`unlock` methods directly. Use an RAII-style locker instead, such as `std::unique_lock`, `std::scoped_lock`, or `std::lock_guard`